# How to: Access a getter from main?

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point, getter

I don't understand why my getter class isn't working.

The getter is set up as follows in a class called Site. (There is a class called PageNode that defines it elsewhere)

```
    private PageNode homePage;

public void setHomePage(PageNode homePage){
    this.homePage = homePage;
}

public PageNode getHomepage(){
    return homePage;
}
```

Now, my understanding is that to reference **homePage** in main, I would just need to call it as follows:

```
PageNode refHomePage = getHomePage();
```

But that doesn't work, and neither does getHomePage by itself.

EDIT FOR EXPANSION: Home page *should* be set up to reference Site with

`SortedADT website = new Site().`

But trying website.getHomepage doesn't work - getHomepage doesn't even show up.

It might be because I've been working on this all day and I'm still learning java, but I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: `Site refHomePage = new Site(); refHomePage.getHomepage()`

Comment: Main is static but getter is not probably you are getting compilation error here.

Comment: You need to call the getter on an actual _object_.  Whose property do you think you are asking for when just calling that getter by itself?  If you can't figure that out, then neither can the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If the getter resides in a class `Site`, as you wrote, you should call it on an instance of that class (as John Is No already suggested). Code in main will then look like this:

```
Site myMainSite = new Site();
//...

PageNode refHomePage = myMainSite.getHomepage();
//...
```

EDIT:
OK, after your edit: you have a parent class `SortedADT`  - does that one have a `getHomepage` method? If not, it won't work either, if your reference is of type `SortedADT`.

Comment: I did not have one. I barely understood the importance of the SortedADT when I wrote it earlier, I'll get on that now.

Is 'public abstract PageNode getHomepage();' correct - specifically, having it be abstract?

Comment: it doesn't need to be abstract... check this tutorial on Polymorphism (the print function they override there):
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html
That's how it basically works if you have inheritance.
Now, if you would like the method to be abstract in SortedADT, that's OK... but that's your design choice and depends on what you are trying to do with that